# Fluent, NHibernate, and PredicateBuilder

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, predicatebuilder

Fluent v1.4, NHibernate v4.0.2.4000, SQL Server

I've seen some posts where Predicate Builder with nested Lambda expressions are not evaluated in NHibernate v3.  Could it be that v4 also has this problem?

```
Public Function TestingWorldQuery() As List(Of EmployeeView)
    Dim EmpView = From q In m_Session.Query(Of EmployeeView)() 
    Dim expr = PredicateBuilder.False(Of EmployeeView)()
    For Each _opco In {"AGRI", "CORP", "FOODS"}
        Dim opco As String = _opco
        expr = expr.Or(Function(x) x.OpCoOrgId = opco)
    Next
    EmpView = EmpView.Where(expr)
    Return EmpView.ToList
End Function
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBitwiseOr' to
>   type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'

---

**CORRECTION** -- After Felipe's suggestion I modified my VB.NET PredicateBuilder Code to use OrElse.  My code is now working.

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Public Module PredicateBuilder
    Public Function [True](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return Function(f) True
    End Function

    Public Function [False](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return Function(f) False
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [OrElse](Of T)(ByVal expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
        Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[OrElse](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [AndAlso](Of T)(ByVal expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
        Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[AndAlso](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
    End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.Net we have `Or` and `OrElse`, you should prefer using the `OrElse` instead `Or` because `Or` is bitwised. Take a look at PredicateBuilder you have and see if you are using `Expression.Or` or `Expression.OrElse`. Change it to `OrElse` if necessary. It is like in C# `|` for `Or` and `||` for `OrElse`.

You could try it using the `Contains` method, which will generate an `IN` sql statement instead of `Or`. Try this:

```
Public Function TestingWorldQuery() As List(Of EmployeeView)

   Return m_Session.Query(Of EmployeeView)().Where(Function(x) {"AGRI", "CORP", "FOODS"}.Contains(x.OpCoOrgId)).ToList()

End Function
```

*Obs: I didn't tested it.*

Comment: The OR was the problem -- I had converted the C# PredicateBuilder code into VB.NET and it used the Or instead of OrElse.  I'll modify my original post to include the revised PredicateBuilder VB.NET code.

Comment: Regarding the "Contains" suggestion.  This has been a proof-of-concept to create a complicated query on-the-fly based on data-driven conditions.  This example doesn't expose the additional AND / OR conditions I will eventually include.  I'll use "Contains" where I can though.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Another Edit:  And needed to be changed to AndAlso

Comment: Yes, `AndAlso` is `&&` operator in C#. It is important to keep the right logical operators.